# Is this a solution for the problem: $\ a^3 + b^3 = c^3\ $ has no nonzero integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, diophantine-equations

Is this a solution for the problem: $\ a^3 + b^3 = c^3\ $ has no nonzero integer solutions?

Suppose $\ a^3 + b^3 = c^3,\ a,b,c \in \mathbb Z^*,\ $then:
$c^3 - b ^ 3 = (c - b)((c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb) = a ^ 3 \quad (1)$
[We can assume that all variables are coprime](http://mathrefresher.blogspot.com/2005/05/coprime-numbers-xn-yn-zn.html), because $\ c - b\ $ divides $\ 3cb,\ a\ $ and $\ c - b\ $ doesnt divides $\ c,\ b,\ $ so
  $c - b = 3 \quad (2),$
from $(1)\ $ and $\ (2)\ $   get $\ 3 (3 ^ 2 + 3 c(c - 3)) = 3^{3}x ^{3},\ c ^ 2 - 3c + 3 = 3x ^3$,
here we see $3$ divides $\ c,\ $and we know $3$ divides $a$, this conflict by assuming.

Edit:

As Nishant commented: "I don't see why $\ c−b\ $ divides $\ 3cb$..."
Divide both side of  $(1)\ $ by $\   (c - b)\ $ get  $\ 3cb = (c - b)^{2}(x^{3} - 1)$

Update:

If$~(c−b)~$ is a single prime or a product of distinct primes or $~(c−b)~\nmid~a~$ and $~(c−b)~$ isn't a cubic number, then $~(c−b)~$ contains factor$~m~$ of $~a,~$divide both side of  $(1)\ $ by $\ (c - b):$

$(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb = (c-b)^{2}x^3 \quad (2),$

from $~(2)~$ if $~m=3~$ or not, we can get $~c~$ or $~b~$ contains factor $~m,~$this conflict by assuming.

If $~(c−b)=1~$ then $~3c^2-3c+1=a^3,~$

from  [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) get:

$$
c = \dfrac{3- \sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}}{6} \\
c = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}+3}{6}
$$
There's no integer solution (As Steven Stadnicki commented,$~\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}~$ isn't an integer, lack of proof)(update: this solved by Jack D'Aurizio see: [How to prove $~\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}~$ isn't an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884565/how-to-prove-sqrt3-sqrt4a3-1-isnt-an-integer)).

(If$~(c−b)~$ is a cubic number, the problem left: $~(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb=x^3~$has no nonzero integer solutions for $~c,~b$)

Comment: I don't see why $c-b$ divides $3cb$...

Comment: That this has no non-zero solutions was proved by Euler, and perhaps earlier by Fermat. The proof is more complicated than the proof for $x^4+y^4=z^4$.

Comment: @Nishant Thanks! See edit.

Comment: Tell me how you get $(3)$ because I am confused. What is $x$? Dividing $(1)$ by $c-b$ gives $3bc = 3bc$.

Comment: I have: $((c-b)^2 + 3cb) = \frac{a^3}{c-b}$ after your instruction to divide by $c-b$ on both sides, not sure how to get $c - b | 3bc$ from here based on your logic

Comment: @iHubble $a^3 = (c-b)^{3}x^3$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas $c-b$ is factor of $a$.

Comment: @miket that still doesn't show to me $\frac{a^3}{c-b}$ itself is a multiple of $c-b$

Comment: Still not seeing it, form 1 says: $(c-b)((c-b)^2 + 3bc) = a^3 \rightarrow ((c-b)^2 + 3bc) = \frac{a^3}{c-b}$ but that doesn't reveal to me any reason why $3bc$ must be a multiple of $c-b$ since it could very well be the case $a = (prime)(c-b)$ unless I'm missing some additional detail here

Comment: Again: $x = \frac{a^3}{(c-b)^3} \rightarrow 3bc = a^3 - (c-b)^2$ we are now assuming the even stronger claim that $\frac{a^3}{(c-b)^3}$ is an integer (I believe that is what you mean to say). You still haven't proved why this must be true. In reference to my prime comment, I made a mistake in what I was trying to write: consider the idea of $(c - b) = a^2$ clearly the statement $\frac{a^3}{c-b}$ yields an integer but in no ways do we have a guarantee $(c-b)|a$ and therefore $\frac{a^3}{c-b}$ need not be divisble by (c-b) therefore 3bc need not be a multiple of (c-b), as far as I see right now

Comment: I don't see the point your trying to make, your single case merely reveals "Sometimes the fraction is indeed an integer" whereas you are right now attempting to prove to everyone that at all times, $\frac{a^3}{(c-b)^3}$ is an integer divisible by $c-b$ whenever $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$, re-read this comment and see if you understand what I mean

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I dont understand that you say $3bc=a^3−(c−b)^2$ while I say $3cb=(c−b)^{2}(x^3−1)$

Comment: To hit your edit: you haven't shown that _of necessity_ there's no integer solution.  You're right that the *algebraic* expression $\frac16(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^3-1}+3)$ isn't a polynomial in $a$, but you still haven't shown any reason why it _can't_ be an integer.  (For a simpler example, $\sqrt{2x^2-1}$ isn't a polynomial expression, but that doesn't mean that it can't be an integer - take $x=12$, for instance.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Yes, this is questionable, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @miket The statement that $\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^3-1}$ isn't an integer is equivalent to the statement that there's no $b$ with $4a^3-1=3b^2$.  This is an _elliptic equation_, and while there's a rich and developed theory behind them, at that point you're veering back to completely standard proofs of the theorem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks, I see.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Unless I am mistaken, it is more accurately an [elliptic curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve). elliptic equation usually refers to [elliptic partial differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation).

Comment: @robjohn Sorry, yes - that's a very easy conflation to make.  I almost never bump into the latter so I always tend to think of the former meaning, but you're definitely correct.

Comment: Tags are misleading. "proof-check" is closer to what you question intends.

Comment: @Brian Thanks, I add the tag proof-verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if $a,b,c$ are relatively prime, $c-b|a^3$ does not necessarily imply that $c-b |a$.

A simple counterexample is $c=13, b=5, a=2$.

Your conclusion (1) is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. $\ c-b\ |\ a^3\ $there's three case: $\ 1.\quad  c-b \nmid a,\quad\ 2. \quad\ c-b \mid a,\ \quad3. \quad\ c-b \nmid a,\ \ c-b \ $ contains other factors of $a$

Comment: $c=9,b=1,a=2$ is simpler. Or $c=11,b=3,c=2$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your argument is that your $x$ in (1) is not an integer (unless you prove it). So even though you have $3cb=(c−b)^{2}(x^3−1)$, it does not imply that $c-b$ divides $3cb$.

Note also that $c-b$ can divide $c$ and $b$ even for coprime $c$ and $b$, contrary to what you say. For example, whenever $c-b=1$, it divides $c$ and $b$, while $c$ and $b$ are necessarily coprime.

Comment: $c−b\ $ divides $\ 3cb\ $ related problem can be solved.$\ c-b=1\ $ this is a problem.

Comment: @miket: $c-b=1$ was only mentioned as a quick example, there are of course other examples where $c$ and $b$ are coprime, yet $c-b$ divides $cb$. Even if $c-b$ does not divide $cb$, it is not true that $c-b\mid 3cb$ implies $c-b\mid 3$. This was only true if $c-b$ were relatively prime to $cb$, which is a much stronger relation than not dividing $cb$.

Comment: And, as I mentioned, the first serious problem with your reasoning is that you rely on an unproven statement, namely that $x$ is an integer.

Comment: There's two problmes left.See update.

Comment: @anonymous To be fair, the _only_ case in which $c-b$ can divide coprime $b$ and $c$ is when $c-b=(\pm)1$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In May 1995, in de Annals of Mathematics, a proof of Andrew Wiles is published that there is no solution with integers for A^n + B^n = C^n for n>2.
See *https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wiles*.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose a^3 + b^3 = c^3 with (a,b,c) = 1. Let
(1) a + b = c + x.  Cubing,
(2) a^3 + 3a^2(b) + 3(a)b^2 + c^3 = c^3 + 3c^2(x) + 3(c)x^2 + x^3.
Subtracting a^3 + b^3 = c^3,
(3) 3ab(a + b) = 3cx(c + x) + x^3. Transposing and substituting (1),
(4) 3(a + b)(ab - cx) = x^3. Therefore, x = 3r, r>0. Substituting x+3r into (4),
(5) 3(a + b)(ab - 3cr) = 27r^3, and dividing by 3,
(6) (a + b)(ab - 3cr) = 9r^3. The left side is divisible by r^3, but r cannot
divide both factors. If so, we would have:
(7) a + b = re and ab - 3cr = rf, (e,f) = 1. now if p is a prime factor of r,
the second of these equations shows that p would divide ab, and therefore, p|a
or p|b. Then referring to the first of these two equations, we have that p divides a and b, contrary to (a,b)= 1. Therefore,r can have no prime factors, so
r = 1. Equation (6) becomes:
(8) (a + b)(ab - 3c) = 9. As before, the left

Comment: I did not downvote. If you embed your expressions in $...$ the post will look much better with the magic of LaTex.