# How to prove $~\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}~$ isn't an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm trying solve: $~a^3 + b^3 = c^3~$ has no nonzero integer solutions.
If $~(c−b)=1~$ then $~c^3-b^3=3c^2-3c+1=a^3,~$

from  [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) get:

$$
c = \dfrac{3- \sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}}{6} \\
c = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}+3}{6}
$$
How to prove $~\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4a^{3}-1}~$ isn't an integer? (eidt: while $~a,\ b,\ c ~$ are nonzero integers)

Comment: Shouldn't you get $c^3 - b^3 = 3c^2 - 3bc + b^2$?

Comment: And why should it be?  $c-b=1$

Comment: By the way $\sqrt{3(4a^3-1)}$ can be an integer in general, just take $a=1$.

Comment: Did you try to verify when $\sqrt{3} \mid \sqrt{4a^3 - 1}$?

Comment: @uomoinverde : Divisibility of algebraic numbers is not something you wanna get into here...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva  If $~a=1~$ then $~c=0$?

Comment: Yes. 11 more to go.

Comment: @individ  If $~c-b=1~$and if$~c-b~$is cubic number,is 2 case of total 3 cases.

Comment: @miket : I said in general. This means you need to exclude cases if you think it holds in your situation.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thanks, I see this and edited the question.

Comment: @miket : You probably mean positive integers, otherwise you can have $a = 1$ and $b = -1$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva If $~c-b=1~$and$~b=-1~$then$~c=0?$

Comment: @miket : Sorry I wrote the wrong example, I meant $a=1$, $b=0$ and $c=1$. Does that work? Either way you want positive integers. There might be stuff happening with signs.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva  Yes, that work. I updated the question time again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prove that
$$ 12 a^3 = b^2+3 \tag{1}$$
has no integer solutions. Since $3\mid$LHS, we must have $b=3c$, hence:
$$ 4 a^3 = 3c^2+1,\tag{2}$$
and $c$ must be odd, hence $c=2d+1$ and:
$$ a^3 = 3 d^2 + 3 d + 1 = (d+1)^3-d^3.\tag{3}$$
So you just have to prove that the difference between two *consecutive* cubes is never a cube (except for $1^3-0^3=1^3$). This is usually achieved by splitting the RHS of $(3)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ and by using the fact that the ring of Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is an euclidean domain, hence a unique factorization domain. We can use Fermat's descent too, since $(3)$ implies $a=3e+1$ and:
$$ 3e(3e^2+3e+1)= d(d+1).\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying with $\sqrt{3}$ only returns an integer when multiplying with certain multiples of three.
Assuming $~4a^3 \equiv 1 (3) \equiv 4(3)$ we check for divisibility by three:

$$4a^3 \equiv4(3) \iff \exists k \in \mathbb N:4a^3-4=3k$$

$$3|4(a^3-1) \iff 3|a^3-1 \iff \Big( 3|a^{3/2}-1 ~~~~\vee~~~~ 3|a^{3/2}+1 \Big)$$

That is not true for $\forall a\not = 1$ and thus your product cannot be an integer.

Comment: $\,3\mid4^3-1\,$