# How to prove $(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb = x^3$ has no nonzero integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying solve:

> $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$ has no nonzero integer solutions.

Only one problem left:  because

$c^3 - b ^ 3 = (c - b)((c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb) = a ^ 3,\quad (1)$

if $~c-b~$ is a cubic number, divide both side of $~(1)~$ by $~(c - b)~$ get

$(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb = x^3.\quad (2)$

How to prove equation $~(2)~$ has no nonzero integer solutions for $~c,\ b,\ x$?

Edit: if $~c,\ b,\ x~$ are integers, [we can assume they are coprime](http://mathrefresher.blogspot.com/2005/05/coprime-numbers-xn-yn-zn.html).

Comment: If, say, $c=1, b=-1$ and $x=1$, we have a solution to (2).

Comment: Unfortunately my answer doesn't fit in the margin.

Comment: @MikeBennett It seems $~c-b=2~$ if $~c=1,b=-1~,2~$ isn't a cubic nubmer?

Comment: How will this lead to $a^3+b^3=c^3$ having no solutions? Most of the time $c-b$ is not the cube of an integer.

Comment: $c=b=x=3$ is a non-zero non-negative solution, if that matters to you?

Comment: @alex.jordan See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882148/is-this-a-solution-for-the-problem-a3-b3-c3-has-no-nonzero-integer

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead $~(c,b)=1,(c,x)=1~$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat's theorem cannot be proved, if you do not know how to solve Diophantine equations.

This approach cannot be used. This equation has a solution.  $$(c-b)^2+3cb=x^3$$

The solutions have the form:

$$x=3(3p^2+s^2)^2$$

$$c=(3p^2+s^2)(36p^2s^2+36ps(3p^2-s^2)-3(3p^2-s^2)^2)$$

$$b=(3p^2+s^2)(36p^2s^2-36ps(3p^2-s^2)-3(3p^2-s^2)^2)$$

$p,s$ - any integer.

You can write another solution. This is equivalent to the equation:

$$x^2+xy+y^2=z^3$$

The solutions have the form:

$$x=s^3+3ps^2-p^3$$

$$y=p^3+3sp^2-s^3$$

$$z=p^2+ps+s^2$$

$$...$$

$$x=s(p^2+ps+s^2)$$

$$y=p(p^2+ps+s^2)$$

$$z=p^2+ps+s^2$$

$$...$$

Will make a replacement.

$$b=3p^2+6ps+2s^2$$

$$t=6s^2+6ps$$

$$q=3p^2+6ps+4s^2$$

The solution has the form:

$$x=q(3b^2-6bt-t^2)$$

$$y=q(3b^2+6bt-t^2)$$

$$z=3q^2$$

Comment: It seems if this then $~3 \mid x~$ and $~3 \mid c~ \text {or}~ b~$,you know we can assume that all variables are coprime.

Comment: There is a hypothesis Bella. These equations are no mutually simple solutions. Than You such decisions are not satisfied?

Comment: $~c,\ b, \ x~$ are coprime.

Comment: No. 't be relatively Prime.

Comment: Take $~p=2,s=5~$ see if $~(c,x)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me have a try:

Suppose $~c,\ b,\ x~$ are nonzero integers, [We can assume that all variables are coprime](http://mathrefresher.blogspot.com/2005/05/coprime-numbers-xn-yn-zn.html),let $~(c-b)^2=y^3,~$ from $~(2)~$ get:

$x^3-y^3=(x-y)((x-y)^{2}+3xy)=3cb\quad (3)$

if $~x-y=3~$ divide both side of  $(3)\ $ by $~3$:

$9 + 3xy= cb,\quad (4)$

form $~(4)~$ we see $~(xy,\ cb)>1~$,this conflict by assuming, if $~x-y \neq 3~$ ,by the same way, we can also get some conflict  (lack of detail).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer for your question. I wont to show that some times this kind of Diophantine equations may have solutions in positive integers.
Consider the equation $$ x^2+y^2=z^3.$$ If we take $$x=n(n^2-3)$$ $$y=3n^2-1$$ for $n>1,$  then the above equation has infinitely many integer solutions.