# Find the non-trivial solutions of the diophantine equation: $a^3+3a^2b=c^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $ a$ and $b$ are co-prime integers >2, can $a^3+3a^2b$ be a cube?

Comment: Writing $a^2(a+3b)$ helps.

Comment: not much... for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $3\nmid a$. Since $a^3+3ab=a^2(a+3b)$ and any prime $p$ dividing $a$  does not divide $a+3b$, we conclude that $a^2$ and hence also $a$ is a cube. Then all we need is that $a+3b$ is also a cube. So let $u$ be an arbitrary integer not divisible by $3$, let $k$ be an arbitry integer relatively prime to $u$. Then $a = u^3$, $b=\frac{(u+3k)^3-u^3}3=3ku^2+9k^2u+9k^3$, $c= u^2(u+3k)$ is a solution. (And all solutions with $3\nmid a$ are of this kind - why?)

Suppose $3\mid a$, say $a=3a_1$. Then $3\mid c$, say $c=3c_1$, and we are led to $a_1^2(a_1+b)=c_1^3$. Since $\gcd(a_1,a_1+b)=1$, we conclude again that $a_1^2$ (and hence $a_1$) is a cube and then that $a_1+b$ is also a cube.
So let $u$ be an arbitrary integer, $k$ an integer relatively prime to $k$.
Then $a= 3u^3$, $b=(u+k)^3-u^3=3k+3k^3+k^3$, $c= 3u(u+k)$ is a solution. (And all solutions with $3\mid a$ are of this kind - why?)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$a=3k$$

$$b=k(q^3-1)$$

$$c=3kq$$

You and another to write. As the imagination will allow.

Comment: Your solution implied that $a,b,c$ are not co-prime since they all have $k$ as a common factor. Thanks.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are coprime, so $k = 1$.

Comment: @DarthGeek Such equations are mutually simple solutions are usually obtained after reduction of numbers. The formulae do not look like coprime. For example there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885181/how-to-prove-c-b-2-3cb-x3-has-no-nonzero-integer-solutions/885372#885372

Comment: @individ the question linked doesn't add the restriction to the variables to be coprime. Here the OP asked for them to be coprime so your answer is the $3$-tuple $(3,q^3-1,3q)$ where $q\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$. I'm not saying that it's a wrong solution. It's a great solution. But perhaps you should remove the $k$ from it to satisfy the demands of the OP.